# After updating MatTableDataSource focus disappears angular

Tags: angular, focus, datasource, angular-material-table

After updating the input element in one row and clicking on the input in the next row, the focus disappears because the datasource gets updated. Is there any way to preserve focus while updating datasource? I have spent a lot of time on it. If someone knows how it can be solved let me know. Thanks.

```
focusedIn(event: Event, article: ArticleDef): void {
    this.activeArticle = article;
    this.facade.active(article.id);
    (event.target as HTMLInputElement).focus();
}
```

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.articles) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ArticleDef & Selectable>(changes.articles.currentValue);
    }
}
```

```
  changeQuantity(event: Event, article: ArticleDef): void {
    this.quantityChange.emit({
      id: article.id,
      name: article.name,
      quantity: parseInt((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done as follow:

```
focusedIn(event: Event, article: ArticleDef): void {
    this.activeArticle = article;
    this.returnArticlesFacade.active(article.id);
    setTimeout(() => {
      (event.target as HTMLInputElement).focus();
    }, 0);
 }
 
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
 if (changes.articles) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ArticleDef & Selectable>(changes.articles.currentValue);

   // Here you can change if condition according to your requirement
   if (this.activeArticle) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        //WE are passing this.activeArticle.id by assuming that it is the id of the element. If it is not then change it according to your requirement
        const element = document.getElementById(this.activeArticle.id).getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        element.focus();
      }, 0);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change the data, Angular "repaint" the table. So you need "wait" the repaint before focus. Generally you can use a setTimeout -without milisecons- or calling to ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()

Really I dont' know if works change your focusedIn function

```
focusedIn(event: Event, article: ArticleDef): void {
    this.activeArticle = article;
    this.facade.active(article.id);

    setTimeout(()=>{
       (event.target as HTMLInputElement).focus();
    })
}
```

Or change when update the table dataSource using a ViewChild (a ViewChild when you have severals tags with the same template referenceVariable gets the first one

```
ViewChild("InputFocus",{read:ElementRef}) input:ElementRef

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
 if (changes.articles) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ArticleDef & Selectable>(changes.articles.currentValue);

    //inside a setTimeout focus the first
    setTimeout(()=>{
       this.input.nativeElement.focus();
    })
 }
```